# cURL basic authenticaton

Tags: php, html, get

I'm trying to access a file from a distant server with

```
$fp = @fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,1);    
fputs($fp, "GET /randomfiletoget.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla\r\n\r\n");
```

But the server needs a HTML authentification.
How should I pass the login/password to access the file?

Thanks!

Comment: `HTML GET with .htaccess` epic title... use cURL.

Comment: What's authentication type? (simple or digest http authentication [see this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html))

Comment: What does `HTML authentification` mean? What authentication scheme is used by the server to protect this resource?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=authentication+curl

Comment: I think it's a BASIC authentification: when I whant to access the page from my browser, I get a Auth window. It's not my server, but I got exactly the same window if I define a AuthUserFile in a .htaccess on my server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To potential downvoters, I wrote `authentification` on purpose. Change `Host` to you domain name. It should return HTML output, with valid username and password.

```
function authentification($url, $username, $password){
    $headers = array(
    "Host=example.com",
    "User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101012 Firefox/3.6.11",
    "Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language=en-us,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate",
    "Accept-Charset=ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
    "Date: ".date(DATE_RFC822)
    );

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    return curl_exec($curl);
}
```

Comment: I get an error:
Warning: curl_exec(): 5 is not a valid cURL handle resource in /myfile.php on line [the return curlr_exec($curl); line]

And yes, I double checked my url and my login/password

Comment: And I've already corrected the "$username:$password" to $username.':'.$password

Comment: There is nothing to correct, except trying to remove curl_close in order to try running the code again sucessfully. (I have removed curl_close).

Comment: If I dont change "$username:$password" to $username.':'.$password PHP variables will not be passed !

Comment: Of course not... but if y put my variables between "", It will be reconized as a string!

Anyway, with my syntax, it seems to work on my server (protected with the htaccess basic auth) but on the distant server, I've got a 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) error...

Comment: It would work just fine, you have bunch of examples here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php, glad you have fixed `authentication` problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

As webarto mentioned in his comment, you should look into [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), it supports basic HTTP auth among many other handy features.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you should use **Host** header too. Todays hosting environments need it in 99%.

Basic http autentication is done with headers and Base64 encoding. This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) will tell you everíthing. Or use [PHP's cURL functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).